# Variable inside a REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

It's possible just delete from for example:

```
input ->> KEYWORD (ASDASD)
```

just delete the "(" and ")" always after a 'KEYWORD'

```
output ->> KEYWORD ASDASD
```

using aRegex its posible or maybe replace?,thanks

input and output are stings

Comment: Any attempts to solve problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what research have you done into regex patterns?

Comment: string = 'KEYWORD (ASDASD)'                --- newstring=string.replace([(|][)]/gmi,''),

Comment: Thanks for editing. That regex pattern definitely won't accomplish your goal. Have you looked at any online references on forming valid regex?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt work, because i have anothers "(", and I just wanna delete that, if ixist before a 'keyword', and i dont know how can be it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = input.replace(/(KEYWORD)\(([^)]+)\)/, "$1 $2")
```

You realize your example has a space after the keyword yeah?  Maybe this instead:

```
text = input.replace(/(KEYWORD)\s*\(([^)]+)\)/, "$1 $2")
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the input text because you don't have a space between KEYWORD and the bracket.

Comment: yeah, his question doesn't match the sample input.

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps

```js
    var str1= "input ->> KEYWORD (ASDASD)";
    str1 = str1.replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
    alert(str1);
```

Comment: Nicely done, that's exactly how I'd do it as well assuming that only brackets the OP wants to remove will ever be included in input. If he wants to specifically only omit bracketed text after the word KEYWORD you would have to add this to the pattern.

Comment: This deletes all brackets.  Not just the ones after a keyword.  input: "(this fails)"

Comment: the problem is if, my str1 is = "insert(a,b) keyword (c)", your code doesnt work, cause you will delete the breackets from insert, and only should be deleted from keyword

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, here is the answer:

```
var RegEx = /(KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2)\s*\(([^)]+)\)/gmi;
var input = 'from(a,b) keyword1 c far(a,b)';
var Result = input.replace(RegEx, "$1 $2");
```

:)